# SonarQube 5.1.1, where to define the file exclusion patterns?

Tags: sonarqube

we want to exclude some files from the SonarQube analysis and I really don't know what I'm missing. Details are as follows:

- SonarQube 5.1.1
- mvn sonar:sonar used for the analysis
- File to be excluded is now visible in the ui with the following path: "src/main/webapp/resources/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css"

I tried to exclude the file via SonarQube UI:
-> Project Dashboard -> Settings -> General Settings -> Exclusions -> Files -> Source File Exclusions

Exclude pattern used:
- src/main/webapp/resources/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css
- **/src/main/webapp/resources/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css
- we also tried **/resources/css/custom-theme/**.css and other stuff

But still the files gets analysed. The output from the analysis shows that the exclusion pattern is used for some modulkes, but ignored for others:

NOT EXCLUDED:

```
[INFO] [08:05:22.015] -------------  Scan LMSTEST-UI-APPLICATION
[INFO] [08:05:22.015] Load module settings
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Base dir: /opt/ccde/jenkins_home/jobs/Build_LMSTEST_trunk/workspace/lmstest-ui/tstdatagenui-application
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Working dir: /opt/ccde/jenkins_home/jobs/Build_LMSTEST_trunk/workspace/lmstest-ui/tstdatagenui-application/target/sonar
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Source paths: src/main/webapp, pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: de_DE
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Index files
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Excluded sources: 
[INFO] [08:05:22.037]   src/main/resources/**/*
[INFO] [08:05:22.050] 47 files indexed
[INFO] [08:05:22.050] 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
```

EXCLUDED:

```
[INFO] [08:05:21.679] -------------  Scan LMSTEST-BACKEND-EAR
[INFO] [08:05:21.679] Load module settings
[INFO] [08:05:21.700] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer
[INFO] [08:05:21.700] Initializer FindbugsMavenInitializer (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] [08:05:21.700] Base dir: /opt/ccde/jenkins_home/jobs/Build_LMSTEST_trunk/workspace/lmstest-backend/lmstest-backend-ear
[INFO] [08:05:21.700] Working dir: /opt/ccde/jenkins_home/jobs/Build_LMSTEST_trunk/workspace/lmstest-backend/lmstest-backend-ear/target/sonar
[INFO] [08:05:21.700] Source paths: pom.xml
[INFO] [08:05:21.700] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_DE
[INFO] [08:05:21.701] Index files
[INFO] [08:05:21.701] Excluded sources: 
[INFO] [08:05:21.701]   src/main/webapp/resources/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css
[INFO] [08:05:21.701]   **/src/main/webapp/resources/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css
[INFO] [08:05:21.701]   LMSTEST-UI-APPLICATION/src/main/webapp/resources/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.csssrc/main/webapp/resources/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css
[INFO] [08:05:21.701]   **/LMSTEST-UI-APPLICATION/src/main/webapp/resources/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.csssrc/main/webapp/resources/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css
[INFO] [08:05:21.702] 1 files indexed
[INFO] [08:05:21.702] 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
```

To summarize my question:
Has anyone an idea why the exclusion pattern is used in the same analysis for one module but not for another. We did not configure any special stuff, its just mvn sonar:sonar.
The configuration was done on the project level - not on the component level.

Thanks for your ideas in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are somehow overriding the exclusion settings at module level. See

```
[INFO] [08:05:22.037] Excluded sources: 
[INFO] [08:05:22.037]   src/main/resources/**/*
```

Settings defined at project level in UI are overriden by settings defined at module level, then by project local properties (ie properties defined in pom.xml) and then by command line.

Comment: That really was the issue here. Thanks.